# previous button functionality on multistep form angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

I am using Angular and implementing multistep form using [THIS Approach](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router).

I am saving one step's data in localstorage on click event of next button and save at the last step but when previous button is clicked pervious form is empty.i want to retain form through all steps.How is it possible? 
According to my perception it should be retained throughout as it is saved in $rootScope too.

Comment: can you add plunker?

Comment: its very lengthy implementation that's why i referenced the tutorial i followed.and "http://plnkr.co/edit/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC?p=preview" is plunker by that tutorial.i just added a previous button.

Comment: and also note down this plunker is retaining data though states

Comment: what you have used for previous button?

Comment: <button ui-sref="form.profile">Previous</button> this button on interest form.

Comment: Adding previous button in plunker is working fine. Might be possible that somehow your controller is getting reloaded on state change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116801/discussion-between-neha-soni-and-user786).